# Numpy concatenate giving error: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1

Tags: python

The dimensions seem to work out, but it's still complaining (*blood pressure building*):

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
y = np.array([5,6,7,8])
m = np.array([9,10])
pointsx = np.concatenate((x,[m[0]]), axis=0)
pointsy = np.concatenate((y,[m[1]]), axis=0)
points = np.concatenate((pointsx.T,pointsy.T), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be two solutions as :

(1) use reshape() to change 1D Vector
Here in case pointsx and pointsy are 1D Vector and to transpose it rather than using .T (which works for higher dimensions)

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
y = np.array([5,6,7,8])
m = np.array([9,10])
pointsx = np.concatenate((x,[m[0]]), axis=0)
pointsy = np.concatenate((y,[m[1]]), axis=0)

points = np.concatenate((pointsx.reshape(-1,1),pointsy.reshape(-1,1)), axis=1)
print(points)
```

Suppose if pointsx = [1,2,3,4] then pointsx.reshape(-1,1) will convert it to

```
[[1]
 [2]
 [3]
 [4]
 [9]]
```

(2) Convert 1D vector to matrix and then use transpose.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
y = np.array([5,6,7,8])
m = np.array([9,10])
pointsx = np.concatenate((x,[m[0]]), axis=0)
pointsy = np.concatenate((y,[m[1]]), axis=0)

points = np.concatenate((np.matrix(pointsx).T,np.matrix(pointsy).T), axis=1)
print(points)
```

Comment: It is highly recommended to paste [formatted code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and not images.

Comment: @YashvanderBamel, Thanks now i have edited the solution with code instead of an image.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to concat a 1D array along its axis 1 (second axis) which is illegal. To fix this you need to reshape it into a 5x1 array and then concat them. Like so:

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
y = np.array([5,6,7,8])
m = np.array([9,10])
pointsx = np.concatenate((x,[m[0]]), axis=0)
pointsy = np.concatenate((y,[m[1]]), axis=0)
pointsx = pointsx.reshape((-1, 1))
pointsy = pointsy.reshape((-1, 1))
points = np.concatenate((pointsx, pointsy), axis=1)
```

The -1 simply tells Numpy to work out the length of that dimension by itself so that the solution is general and doesn't just apply to an array of length 5.